# Creating a unique list with the each subsequent item from a series of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

How can i create a new list combing the first values of my old lists and then the second ones etc..

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
list_2 = [1,2,3,4]
list_3 = [1,2,3,4]
new_list = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pure python:

You can use `zip`:

```
new_list = list(map(list, zip(list_1,list_2,list_3)))

>>> new_list
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

## Alternative:

`numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
new_list = np.array([list_1,list_2,list_3]).T.tolist()

>>> new_list
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it using list comprehensions.

```
new_list = [list(args) for args in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we `enumerate` one list the index from that list to all 3

```
new_list = [[list_1[i], list_2[i], list_3[i]] for i, _ in enumerate(list_1)]
# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```